# How to call an Epson TM-U220PD in Java to print USB port

Tags: java, windows, printing, epson, javapos

I'm trying to print on a EPSON TM-U220PD in windows 7, I', using Java for do It.
I'm developing a software for print orders in a restaurant. I did the software in linux, when I connect the printer on linux, printer works excellent. But when I connect the printer on windows It's not work. 
My drivers are good, I know because I can print test page, but when I'm going to the software, printer not works.
Printer is configurated in a port "USB001"
my code is here:

```
    public void printLocalOrder(ArrayList<String> orderArray, int n) {

    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("USB001"); //Here is the problem
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
        PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(buffer);
        ps.write(0x1B);
        ps.write("M");
        ps.write(1);            
        for (String orderArray1 : orderArray) {
        ps.write(orderArray1);
        }
        ps.write(0x1B);
        ps.write("d");
        ps.write(4);
        ps.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I have tried put the printer name so:

```
     FileWriter file = new FileWriter("Ticketeadora"); //Name printer
```

But It's not works.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the facilities in Java that were made for printing?

Comment: I do not know what they are. Can you tell me about them ?

Comment: Didn't you do any research about [printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) in Java? That's quite a poor way to start developing *anything*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to read and I'm going to search always before to start developing.
But, respect to my problem, how I can solve It ?

Comment: I think you have a big problem here. Why would you think that `new FileWriter("USB001");` connects to a printer?

Comment: because when I'm working on linux, I use this command for call the printer. `new FileWriter("/dev/usb/lp2");` lp2 is like linux detect printer.

Comment: Linux and `/dev/usb/lp2` is one thing, accessing the line printer through the file system. Windows and `USB001` is not the same thing at all. What error are you getting?

Comment: That's the strangest thing. When I'm going to print, There is not any error. The process "continue well" there are not exceptions or another thing.

Comment: And is there a file named `USB001` in the directory where you're running the program in?

Comment: No, There is not a file named USB001. `USB001` is the port where I configured my printer. And I have been searching information about how to configure this in windows and they call for example port `LPT1` or `COM4` but I have connected printer for USB. I don't know how I can call my printer for the port USB

Comment: Well, you can't. You can try [tricking](http://superuser.com/questions/182655/how-do-i-simulate-a-parallel-lpt-printer-with-a-usb-printer) to have it accessible through `LPT1`, but your current approach is and always was flawed. The wise thing to do would be to use the proper printing facilities, which I already linked to you.

Comment: OK Kayaman. I'm going to use the code you send me with printing facilities. I'm going to do tests. but I'm worried because I have some ESC commands for print with format and other things. With the link you send me I can use this commands normal ?

Comment: Nope. You probably shouldn't have gone with the line printer approach to begin with. Now you'll have to recode it or hack with the `NET USE` approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for help me. When I have done everything that you said me. I'm going to comment you for that you post a solution and I can qualify you positive

Comment: Alright. Just read up on your choices before you start doing anything. I haven't worked with the Print API, but it should provide you with better tools and better platform independence than the line printer approach.

Comment: Hi Kayaman I found a solution to my problem. First I followed your redomendation, I used Printable library and other designed by Java.
Second, I found this link, [Example printable java](http://www.mets-blog.com/java-pos-thermal-printer-example/) and I did everything there. Thanks so much for open my mind and help me

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

[escpos-coffee](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee) is a Java library for ESC/POS printer commands. Can send text, images and barcodes to the printer. All commands are send to one OutputStream, then you can redirect to printer, file or network.

Code example:

```
  PrintService printService = PrinterOutputStream.getPrintServiceByName("printerName");
  PrinterOutputStream printerOutputStream = new PrinterOutputStream(printService);
  EscPos escpos = new EscPos(printerOutputStream);
  escpos.writeLF("Hello Wold");
  escpos.feed(5);
  escpos.cut(EscPos.CutMode.FULL);
  escpos.close();
```